# Remote EEG detection / reading

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation, biophysics, electronics

I recently noted that Philips, Accenture, and Emotive grouped together to create a proof of concept that would assist ALS patients to gain greater control of their lives through brain, voice, and eye commands.  See this link [here](http://www.newscenter.philips.com/us_en/standard/news/press/2014/20140805-Accenture-and-Philips-announce-proof-of-concept-app-to-show-how-ALS-patients-could-gain-greater-control.wpd).

While a breakthrough for ALS patients, it remains limited as such that the patient must wear a headpiece, or use close to surface biomedical implants for the EEG to be read.  This made me wonder how one might 'read' EEG signals using remote means?   This could be used for many purposes: those suffering with ALS, remote monitoring of elderly or special needs patients, hospitals and emergency care units, combat air pilots and other military purposes, and etc...

I am curious as to how one might be able to remotely detect biological EMF signals.  In my review thus far I am to understand that noise would be an issue in obtaining a clear EMF reading, as most devices require close, physical contact, or for the subject to be secured in a EMF 'clean room'.   I have found a lot of patents regarding how this could be done, but always seem to be able to find a way of defeating them (some flaw in their design/theory).

I am to understand that lower frequencies penetrate the body best, and the depth depends on the frequency used.  I also have read that the human body works as a dipole antenna.  However, I am to understand that biological matter is nonlinear, and as such signals are not modulated when passing through tissue.

- Could this be done, perhaps, by using externally applied rf signals?
- Is there any point/part in the body to which the biologically generated signals are naturally modulated, or combined (eSum) - perhaps for processing by the brain?

Thanks!

Comment: Remotely? Basically you can't. The human skull is a very good insulator for neural signals, and what little can be measured, has been measured as well as it can be . Honestly, don't waste your time on this, you are not going to invent a better EEG mousetrap anymore than generations of very smart people before you. What can potentially be done, is better signal processing and, with invasive methods, better subcranial sensing, for the latter, of course, you need to ask a brain surgeon.

Comment: I'm not sure that physics is the place for this question, seems more of a biology question.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Biologists don't have the slightest idea of how to measure small electrical signals like EEG signals. The hard work of building useful EEG equipment is done by physicists and electrical engineers. We are returning the favor by having no clue how to interpret the signals that we help them to measure. I think that's called interdisciplinary science. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne: Surely medical physics could answer the question about the rf signals, but the second question seems to be pure biology.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I can probably answer that from an FDA perspective: by the time there are non-linear effects in the body, the device would have far exceeded safe limits and would probably be considered a health risk (i.e. there is no way it could be approved for the general public, if at all). I am not sure there is even a regime in which one could do that without destroying neurons unintentionally, although I would give the OP points for originality.

Comment: @CuriousOne apparently you can: http://igert.eng.usf.edu/students/hbenjamin/pdf_docs_abstracts/harland_remote_detection.pdf

I heard they achieved even better results in 2008 but am struggling to find the paper... apparently they got to a distance of 40cm in an unshielded environment.

Comment: @AlexMurray: That paper is a trivial application of capacitively coupled electrodes. Similar things have been done for quite a while for ECG signals. While it can be done, there is not much advantage to it, as it degrades both the waveforms and the SNR. I would very much doubt that EEG can be detected reliably from 40cm in unshielded rooms WITH realistic noise. You can always use an unshielded room without noise and actually get better results than from a shielded room with... that's why some folks like to go into the fields/woods to do sensitive rf noise measurements!

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy amplify the brain signals remotely.
In fact, the skull shows no resistance to electromagnetic interference and amplify uV voltages is quite easy.

Comment: Could i invite you to email me?